# Preferred way of using UiBinder with multiple screens

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

We have a GWT app that has multiple screens, based off of a menu.  So App loads user sees

- Do This
- Do That

Each menu item loads a different screen.  What is the best way to switch the screens.  Right now what I do roughly is

```
RootPanel.get(CONTENT).remove(menu);
RootPanel.get(CONTENT).add(new DoThisScreen());
```

I ask this because it seems on IE 8 (and I am sure 7,6) that the DoThisScreen is basically not recognize by IE's Developer Tool (wannabe firebug tool, when you press F12).  Using IE's dev tool I tell it to highlight a textbox in the DoThisScreen, for some reason it won't highlight it or list it in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing in GWT is fine. This issue is with the IE8 Developer Tools:

When the contents of the HTML page change, you have to hit the Refresh button in the IE8 Developer Tools window (make sure you've got the "HTML" tab selected in the Developer Tools window) before it will show you the new items that have been added to the DOM.